# Regex Binary multiple of 4

Tags: regex, binary

How can I write a Reg-ex Expression to check whether a string is a binary multiple of 4? I am not good at making DFA and finding expressions.

Comment: what do you mean by binary multiple of 4?

Comment: I mean this "1100100", the binary number in the string is a multiple of 4

Comment: Perhaps you should write out some numbers that are multiples of 4 with their binary equivilents and see if you notice a pattern.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A multiple of 4 in binary is any binary number that ends with `00`, so this regexp should do it:

```
^(?:[10]*00|00?)$
```

If you mean a multiple of 4 in decimal, I wouldn't do that with a regexp, except perhaps to verify that it's a number. Then I'd parse it and check whether `number % 4` is zero.

Comment: Although, it's not all *that* bad, in decimal... `^[0-9]*([02468][048]|[13579][26])$` would probably be sufficient...

Comment: Except it doesn't match 4, ha! `^([048]|[0-9]*([02468][048]|[13579][26]))$`

Comment: This answer doesn't include zero! Zero is also divisible by 4! So, the answer should be ^(0|(10|111*0)(10|111*0)*0)*$